# Joomla- JomSocial User Registration- Auto approve users

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I am using Joomla 3.1.5 and JomSocial 3.0.4 Pro extension. I want the users to be auto approved instead of approval by admin. I am new to Joomla & JomSocial.

Please tell how to do that. Thank you..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla configuration

Comment: This is not a SO question. Try asking on the [JomSocial forum](http://www.jomsocial.com/community).

Comment: This is joomla simple logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla go to Users > User Manager > Options Button

Change the option for "New User Account Activation" to "None"